# TS + Sequelize - Specifying the type of fields on the model

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I have these two lines of code. I cannot find any docs for them:

```
declare setClasa: HasOneSetAssociationMixin<Clasa, 'id'>;
declare createClasa: HasOneCreateAssociationMixin<Clasa>;
```

I can't really understand the difference between the two. What is each of them supposed to do? What's the difference between Set and Create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set` is about setting a foreign key value in the existing `Clasa` record and `Create` is about creating a new `Clasa` record and associating it with the record on the other end of the association.